# Running AnyDesk before login on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: login

I'm an experienced Windows user trying to get into Linux with Ubuntu 18.04. Trying to get Anydesk running before login.

All I can find information on is having Anydesk start after a user has logged on, i.e. with Startup Applications. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFb4v.png  This is NOT what I need! I'm hoping I can get Anydesk running before the login screen so I can login remotely.

Alternatively, would anyone recommend a different screen sharing option? I got XRDP running, as per this link http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11336 and I wasn't very happy with it. Although it would allow me to login, the screen updating seemed quite slow and poorly optimized for network bandwidth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start anydesk on boot and without login in.

You have to add this sentence:

```
anydesk --service &> /dev/null &
```

at the end of this script:

/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc, but make sure it has execution permisions. It works on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Can you explain or give more detail how this works? I tried this on Ubuntu 22.04 and it's not working for me. I made sure that /bin/anydesk and /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc have +x permissions (they already did, I double checked) but no good, it doesn't let me connect even after: sudo service restart gdm && sudo service restart gdm3 && sudo service restart display-manager, I just get Status: desk_rt_ipc_error like before.

Comment: I just realized it's possible gdm3 login screen is using Wayland which means it wouldn't read that X11 file, so I guess I could try setting WaylandEnable=false. Instead, I just enabled autologin also with xtrlock (swaylock would work for Wayland) which works better for my purposes.

Comment: Try this sentence

anydesk --service &> /some/place/you_know/log.txt &

and there show some errors.

Sorry for delay

Answer (score 5):

I found a easy solution for me. I click on the network symbol on the top of the page, select "show network info" close the window. Now the anyway window disapear and you can login.

Comment: Wooow, this worked for me, (Ubuntu 16.04) thank you so much, I was wondering how to get by this :-)

Comment: I am here for the "Wooow" factor too. pynoob you are awesome.

Comment: HOW? Still, don't understand how to run anydesk before log in the remote computer

Comment: The top of which page?

Comment: where is network symbol?

Comment: -1 as this does not describe nor solve my original problem (also for 3 other users). I would cast my downvote away if you update the answer.

Comment: Very unhelpful response. Doesn't provide any information about the context of the descibed actions. Please clerify what page and what network info icon.

Answer (score 4):

So far the only solution I was able to find is - set Your account to autologin without password and then use automatic lock after login (xtrlock or options mentioned here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1564601 or here: https://superuser.com/questions/718879/lock-screen-after-auto-login-debian-ubuntu)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here. I recommend to edit this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also How do I write a good answer? for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: Thx for feedback, I will get into it when I will have spare time :) (Meanwhile I think it deserves a place here as the only existing answer so far, at least) If anyone would take my answer and refactor it into something better before me, he deserves the points for it surely :) (Or if better answer arises :) )